# Is a Java to PHP Bridge neccessary for this situation?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

We are dealing with an API that sends us a significant amount of data. I'm still in the architecture phase of the application, but my strategy is going to be to use PHP for the frontend portion and then for dealing with the API Id use a set of java classes and access them through calling a java file from the `exec` function in php. There's too much data for PHP to deal with this, which is why I am deciding to use Java, but I was curious if it would be ideal instead to use a java-to-php bridge? It says that using this bridge is significantly better for performance, but it would take some time to figure out how to install it and get it working.

Truthfully, I just want to call java classes with `exec` but if initiating a new JVM seems to be considerably intensive than I need to rethink my strategy.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) could be one option: using [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) or [IBM's WebSphere sMash](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0809_phillips/0809_phillips.html) might be another. I've used all three options, but my personal preference is using an API. Calling java via exec isn't really an API

Comment: My question though is if it is really neccessary for me to look into a java bridge or can i just use php exec without degrading performance

Comment: Calling exec() will have overheads that are eliminated by Quercus or sMash, when you're actually running your PHP within a JVM and can call Java class methods directly from your PHP

Comment: Im not in favor of a java to php bridge. Can it support custom java classes? All I see are standard Java.IO classes. Quercus seems to be a complete reimplementation of PHP, which is out of the question (unless I'm reading it incorrectly). I'm looking through IBM now.

Comment: IBM is also a complete re-implementation of PHP

Comment: Id be using an API via Java. My point is Im trying to use Java for the API data management versus PHP, because frankly I dont trust PHP for handling such large amounts of data.

Comment: If you distrust PHP that much, then don't use it in the first place

Comment: I don't distrust PHP, infact I'm a large supporter of PHP, but I have a problem with using PHP for handling large amounts of data processing. That's about the only task I prefer to not use PHP with.

Comment: PHP can handle some pretty large volumes of data, and fairly intense processing, though you do need to be a bit canny with memory usage to get the best out of it

Comment: Thanks. Then I will try PHP as well. Do you see my question though? Do you think I should consider trying PHP or work first on a compiled language?

Comment: @jkushner what ammounts of data are we talking about? What would averaged-out values for these be Size/Concurrency/RequestsPerMinute?
What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: I think there are some high-activity/volume sites running on PHP now (and I'm not simply talking about FB with its modified platform): I've worked on 250rps sites myself. Depending on what you need doing - avoiding known problem areas like photo manipulation or data-mining terrabytes of data (which should be down to a database anyway) - PHP is likely to be perfectly adequate. Certainly consider prototyping in PHP. But having an extra layer between PHP and your existing API is additional overhead and additional complexity, and should really be avoided if possible

Comment: @MarkBaker I agree with what you say about adding an additional layer. Boris, I don't have an exact calculation yet. I would prefer to not write the API communication layer twice, so maybe I should write it in PHP and then if that does not suffice try java. Quick question though, do you know any good OAuth PHP Libraries that take in an API key and an API secret?

Comment: @MarkBaker I created a new question. The two are close but this one specifically just asks about JVM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507375/is-instantiating-a-new-jvm-for-every-server-request-a-large-load

Comment: As pointed out in answers to the JVM question, calling exec will be a big overhead as it runs up an extra process: using a java socket server, or a restful java API will certainly be more efficient; and you can use PHP sockets or a curl request (I like guzzle as a wrapper for such requests) to communicate with a java daemon or tomcat/whatever servlet container for communicating with a "persistent" java app

Comment: @jkushner I can agree with Mark Baker on both points in the previous comment. Both from personal experience.
1. Use Sockets
2. Guzzle is a really nice wrapper for such cUrl requests